# Third party apps installation when 'unknown source' option is disabled

Tags: applications, apk, unknown-sources, samsung-galaxy-s-8

Instead of using my company phone, I set up my company email account (MS Exchange Active) on my personal phone. So now I can organise and overview my private and work events in the calendar etc. Also reply to work emails from my personal device.

However, our IT department is pushing the company policy onto my phone and disabling the option for "unknown sources" (third party apps installation using apk file).

Does anyone have a workaround to be able to install third party apps on my phone while the policy is enforced? In other words, I can't enable the "unknown source" option on my Samsung Galaxy S8.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Being technical, if the default app store doesn't use an encrypted connection (SSL/TLS), you can perform a MITM attack, and intervene the downloading process, and replace the app with an APK you've prepared.

A computer running Linux is strongly recommended, but a more user-friendly approach could be using [zANTI](https://www.zimperium.com/zanti-mobile-penetration-testing) to intervene.